# Get-EXOMailbox and expand AzureADGroupMember

Tags: powershell

I want to obtain a list of all shared mailboxes and expand the group membership.

I have the following

```
Get-EXOMailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | select *user  | where { ($_.User -Notlike 'NT*' -and $_.User -Notlike '*@*')   }
```

This returns all the group memberships.
How do I pipe this into the following please?

```
Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString <variable> | Get-AzureADGroupMember | Select DisplayName, Mail
```

I have tried this:

```
$groupnames = (Get-EXOMailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | select *user  | where { ($_.User -Notlike 'NT*' -and $_.User -Notlike '*@*')   })
    
foreach($item in $groupnames){
   $item
   Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $item | Get-AzureADGroupMember | Select DisplayName, Mail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first command gives you a list of groups you need to store this information in a variable:

```
$groups = Get-EXOMailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | select *user  | where { ($_.User -Notlike 'NT*' -and $_.User -Notlike '*@*')   }
```

I assume the array $groups looks like this:

```
$groups = @(
    "ACL_Awards Mailbox Access"
    "ACL_Business Analyst Mailbox Access" 
    "ACL_Callsafe Operatives" 
    "ACL_Certs Mailbox"
    "ACL_Check Calls Mailbox Access"
)
```

Then the following should work.

```
$result = @(   
    #Build filter
    $filterArray = @(
        $groups | %{
            "DisplayName eq '$_'"
        }
    )
    $filterString = $filterArray -join " or "
    #Query Groups
    $groups = get-AzureAdGroup -filter $filterString 
    foreach ($group in $groups){
        #Query members
        $members = get-AzureAdGroupMember -all -objectId $group.objectId
        #Build objects to return
        $attrsht = @{
            group=$group.DisplayName
            members=$members
        }
        New-Object -typename psobject -Property $attrsht
    }
)
```

Comment: The first command returns a list like this

Comment: User                                             
----                                                          
ACL_Awards Mailbox Access                      
ACL_Business Analyst Mailbox Access            
ACL_Callsafe Operatives                      
ACL_Certs Mailbox                            
ACL_Check Calls Mailbox Access

Comment: which attribute does contain the group information and what kind (Id, Name) of?

Comment: ah now I got it - those ACL_* are the group names right? the string "user----" is also part of the output?

Comment: yes that is correct